# I am getting this error: requests.exceptions.ProxyError:

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I am running this simple code:

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')

print(x.text)
```

However, I am getting this error

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='w3schools.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /python/demopage.htm (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)'))))
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a proxy issue. So I just set up proxy dict for https and http and pass proxies as argument like this:

```
import requests
proxies = {
   'http': '*********',
   'https': '*********',
}
x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm', proxies =proxies )

print(x.text)
```